# sourceMappingURL exception

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

Whenever I debug I hit the following exception in every js file generated from ts when I hit the last line in the js file:

```
 //@ sourceMappingURL=xxxx.js.map
```

> Unhandled exception at line 103, column 5 in http://blah.com/ts/libs/xxxx.js
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'xxxx' is undefined

I presume this is because of the ts files and hence the js files not being in the root of the project and hence the url statement is incomplete.  I've looked without success to find out how to augment the path... anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Should be painless: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvD_ia7vkkA Are you doing concatenation OR moving files around?

Comment: no concatenation no moving ts/js
file structure:

root\
     references.ts
     app.ts
     libs\
          xxxx.ts
     interfaces\
          xxxx.d.ts

Comment: I also have this issue. Just started happening for no reason. The .map files are there.

Looks like the issue is to do with conditional comments in IE. They've changed the syntax to //# for new versions of the spec to avoid this issue. But that doesn't solve the problem and why it just starts happening.

Comment: This sounds like an issue of your combination of the version of Visual Studio and Internet Explorer you have installed. Maybe check for updates to one or both of them?